# Intel Nuc Nuc5i3ryh on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: intel

do you know if Intel Nuc Nuc5i3ryh will work with Ubuntu 16.04? I'm thinking about buying one, I use a virtual machine of Android in VirtualBox too, don't know if it will be able to run it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a problem with it ... I run a server running 16.04 that is running on an old quad core AMD 2.8ghz processor .. it is running android-x86 and windows 10 in vm's and also run several servers and zoneminder with 3 cameras. Only suggestion is ... make sure you put in a decent amount of ram... android-x86 needs 2 gig by itself and it really doesn't like sharing :D I had 8G in mine and was running but it was not doing very well .. I bumped it to 16G and now it runs fine.. a bit slow but .. with all I have running ... it still seems to do the job.

The NUC has a 2.1 ghz dual core but I think it should still be able to handle the OS and running android-x86 without a problem. Its not going to be blazing fast but it should be able to get the job done.